# For Julia saving output to txt/CSV file?

Tags: csv, save, output, julia, txt

I am dealing with output saving using Julia 1.4.2 on Win10, I have tried several ways referred to [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.open). But nothing works for me.
The output I want to save look like this

```
julia> sim_result
GpABC.SimulatedABCRejectionOutput(3, 1465, 20000, 1.0, [4.5398045285832636 16.341298256602684 0.8528241692701137; 2.2014098882111117 11.88704704892733 1.8060482719350048; … ; 3.4569125171576727 14.206295598447817 1.2527525901911478; 1.1086538611233734 16.95205292134931 0.7814523160265465], [0.8718784407104312, 0.9897439825224637, 0.7361435718656393, 0.7863129137954922, 0.8097276891293583, 0.7167559341428585, 0.6600858843737456, 0.7420732257406872, 0.8085779131629843, 0.7603566788770011  …  0.9172504543539195, 0.5578993725435081, 0.8377191750525664, 0.7847440234430122, 0.6465487321194205, 0.716785821691151, 0.2596989086130145, 0.7210284576525666, 0.9855259563757373, 0.5775313512469311], [0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899  …  0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899, 0.0006825938566552899])
```

And its structure is
 `GpABC.SimulatedABCRejectionOutput(::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Float64, ::AbstractArray{Float64,2}, ::AbstractArray{Float64,1}, ::StatsBase.Weights)`
I want to save the `::AbstractArray{Float64,2}` to a TXT or CSV file.

Comment: Solved! by "You’ll need to find out how the array is stored in your sim_result object by doing fieldnames(typeof(sim_result)). Let’s assume the field is called data, you can then either do using DelimitedFiles; writedlm("output.txt", sim_result.data) to write a simple delimited text file, or using CSV; CSV.write("output.csv", (data = sim_result.data, )) (note the comma which creates a NamedTuple) to write a csv." from [this link](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/saving-output-to-txt-csv-file/59636)

Comment: Also try `dump(sim_results)` to see what is going on.

Answer (score 7):

Happy to provide this as the actual answer - it's always good to cross-reference if you post in more than one place, I had missed this here.

Step 1: find out how you can access the array - it will be a field of the `sim_result` object, and you can use `fieldnames` to find out how the fields of this type are called. You need to use `typeof(sim_result)`, as `fieldnames` operates on types.

```
julia> fieldnames(typeof(sim_result))
(:n_params, :n_accepted, :n_tries, :threshold, :population, :distances, :weights)
```

This tells you that you can access the array as `sim_result.population`.

Step 2: How to write an array to txt or csv? The simplest solution is to use the `DelimitedFiles` standard library, which can write a delimited file to text:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> writedlm("output.txt", sim_result.population)
```

Alternatively, if you want to write a csv file you should use the `CSV` package, which needs to be installed in your current environment. Then you can do:

```
julia> using CSV

julia> CSV.write("output.csv", (data = sim_result.population, ))
```

Note that the comma in `(data = sim_result.population, )` creates a `NamedTuple`, which is the simplest table-compatible object in Julia (the `CSV` library expects a table as the argument to `CSV.write()`)