# Julia history storage with command line outputs

Tags: command-line, julia, history

Is there a method to store the command line outputs to a file in Julia.

The command history can be seen at `.julia\logs\repl_history.jl` in Windows OS.

I wish to store command line output also to a file automatically.
? command outputs also.

Whatever is shown in the julia command line, the whole text should be stored into a file.
Is there a way to do this.

found a similar qn : [For Julia saving output to txt/CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172535/for-julia-saving-output-to-txt-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

If you run Julia in REPL mode in Widows using PowerShell, you can do the following in PowerShell:

1. Open the left upper corner menu and in Defaults, change the buffer size to something large enough for your needs, say 500.
2. After running Julia to do what you need, go the the left hand corner menu and choose Edit - Select all, then Copy.  Paste to an editor.